# strftime is always showing am for times (even for "pm" time also) for every datetime entry in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, strftime

iam saving current date and time in database as checkin time in db. by using Time.now. and when i query the database like this iam always getting the time in "am" only even for time in "pm" also.

```
 @curr_emp_attendace = current_employee.punch_in_outs.where("YEAR(check_in) = ? and MONTH(check_in) = ?",Time.now.strftime("%Y") ,Time.now.strftime("%m") )
```

and in view iam displaying like this
`<%= attendace.check_in.strftime("%a %d, %H:%M %P")` when i display like this iam always getting the "am" only for the time (for times in "pm") also. what might be the reason iam not understanding.

Comment: what value do you get in `attendace.check_in` variable.

Comment: this is the value iam getting. 2015-07-01 10:53:22 UTC, actually my system date is wrong. thats why the date is wrong in this  value.

Comment: ok, is your problem resolved?

Comment: no. it still showing am only for the pm times also. i set my current system time properly.

Comment: please paste both the values which you are trying to convert.

Comment: i want to display the checkins and checkouts for the user selected month and year. for that i wrote the above query. and in views iam displaying like this  <%= attendance.check_in.strftime("%a %d, %H:%M %P") %>    ,  <%= attendance.check_out.strftime("%a %d, %H:%M %P") %>

Comment: Paste the values which you have in database.

Comment: for checkin field this is the value iam having  2015-06-01 07:48:25 in db.

Comment: for check_out 2015-06-01 07:48:28

Comment: As you see the difference between both is only 3 seconds
`2015-06-01 07:48:25` AND `2015-06-01 07:48:25` so if you convert these it will always return am for both.

Comment: Please try to save the values in database in 24hrs format

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@curr_emp_attendace = current_employee.punch_in_outs.where(:check_in => Time.now)
```

Comment: actually i wrote that query for getting the checkins for the selected month and the selected year by the user.

Comment: Is check_in a datetime field?